# Fill in gaps in an array where a dash appears?

Tags: php

I have a text box that a user can paste a string of comma separated numbers and it puts that into an array.  However, in some cases that string may contain numbers separated by a dash and I need to fill in the missing numbers where that dash appears.

Example:

```
1, 4, 7, 20-25, 31, 46, 100
```

Needs to become:

```
1, 4, 7, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 31, 46, 100
```

How might I go about doing this? The gap wont always be 5 numbers and there could be more than one set of dashed numbers in the string that is input.

Comment: Grab the input, explode on ",", strip the whitespace. From here you have an array of your numbers. Iterate through them and strpos for any dashes or just explode on "-". That'll give you the starting number and the ending number, fill in the gaps with a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way, without a regex:

It is:

1. Parsing the input string with [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) to separate it into its individual elements, then trimming whitespace around each element with [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) and [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map).
2. Iterating over each element, searching for a dash. If it finds a dash, it found a range of numbers, so it separates them into the start and end indexes by [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode)ing on the dash, and forms the correct range between `$start` and `$end` with [`range()`](http://php.net/range). It then merges that newly formed range with what has already been formed as the result using [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge).
3. If, during iteration, it didn't find a dash, it assumes you have a literal number, and adds just that number to the resulting array.

That's it!

```
$input = '1, 4, 7, 20-25, 31, 46, 100';
$entries = array_map( 'trim', str_getcsv( $input));

$result = array();
foreach( $entries as $entry) {
    if( strpos( $entry, '-') !== false) {
        list( $start, $end) = explode( '-', $entry);
        $result = array_merge( $result, range( trim($start), trim($end)));
    } else {
        $result[] = $entry;
    }
}
```

You can see from [this demo](http://3v4l.org/YFkGd) that it produces:

```
Array (
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 20
    [4] => 21
    [5] => 22
    [6] => 23
    [7] => 24
    [8] => 25
    [9] => 31
    [10] => 46
    [11] => 100 )
```

**Edit:** To form the resulting string, instead of the array, you just need a call to [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode), like so:

```
echo implode( ', ', $result);
```

This will produce:

```
1, 4, 7, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 31, 46, 100
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without the using a regular expression.

- Get the user input, explode with `,` as the delimiter, and you'll get an array of all numbers.
- Now use an `if` statement to check if the string contains a dash.
- If it does, `explode` it again with the delimiter `-`. Now you'll get two numbers
- Use `range()` to create an array of numbers within that range
- Use `implode()` to join them by a comma.

As a useful function:

**Code:**

```
function fill_string_gaps($input) 
{
    $parts = explode(',', $input);
    $resultArray = array();

    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if(strpos(trim($part), '-')) {
            list($num1, $num2) = explode('-', $part);
            $expanded_num_array = range($num1, $num2);
            $resultArray = array_merge($resultArray, $expanded_num_array);
        } else {
            $resultArray[] = trim($part);
        }        
    }
        $comma_separated = implode(', ', $resultArray);
        return $comma_separated;

}
```

**Usage:**

```
$input = '1, 4, 7, 20-25, 31, 46, 100';
echo fill_string_gaps($input;)
```

**Test cases:**

```
echo fill_string_gaps('1-5');
echo fill_string_gaps('1-5, 12, 24');
echo fill_string_gaps('2, 2, 4, 5-8');
```

**Output:**

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 24
2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

**[See it in action!](http://codepad.org/reVt6Uy9)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = '1, 4, 7, 20-25, 31, 46, 100';
$elts = explode(',', $data);
$res = array();

foreach ($elts as $elt) {
    $elt = trim($elt);

    if (preg_match('/(\d+)-(\d+)/', $elt, $matches) === 1) {
        $res = array_merge($res, range($matches[1], $matches[2]));
    } else {
        $res[] = intval($elt);
    }
}

var_dump($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple code :

1. split string by delimiter `,` with `explode()`;
2. remove space from the beginning and end of a string with `trim`;
3. function `array_map` is used so you don't need to do `foreach` loop just to apply `trim()` to every element;
4. create empty array where you will store new elements;
5. iterate over each number or range with `foreach`;
6. do points 1., 2. and 3. again on every iteration;
7. split string by delimiter `-` with `explode()` even if string doesn't have delimiter `-` in it; result will be array with one or multi elements;
8. if point 6. has array with multiple elements, that means that there is range involved, so use function `range()` to create an array containing a range of elements;
9. store new numbers to point 4. array with `array_merge()` function;
10. when point 4. array is full generated; sort values with `sort()`, so you don't have output like `5, 3, 1, 4` etc. (delete this function if you don't need this functionality);
11. remove duplicates with `array_unique()`, so you don't have output like `4, 4, 4, 4, 5` etc. (delete this function if you don't need this functionality)
12. to convert array back to string like you inputed, use `implode()` function.

|

```
function fillGaps($s) {
    $s = array_map('trim', explode(',', $s));
    $ss = [];
    foreach ($s as $n) {
        $n = array_map('trim', explode('-', $n));
        if (count($n) > 1) $n = range($n[0], end($n));
        $ss = array_merge($ss, $n);
    }
    sort($ss); # remove if you don't need sorting
    $ss = array_unique($ss); # remove if duplicates are allowed
    return implode(', ', $ss);
}
```

#### Example :

Your example :

```
echo fillGaps('1,    4, 7, 20   -   25, 31, 46, 100');
# 1, 4, 7, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 31, 46, 100
```

This code will also work for multiple gaps, like :

```
echo fillGaps('100-105-110');
# 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110
```

You can even go reverse :

```
echo fillGaps('10-5');
# 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
# or remove function sort() and output will be 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5
```

Remove duplicates :

```
echo fillGaps('2-4, 4, 4, 5');
# 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution :**[DEMO HERE](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/309-z6i)**

- First delete spaces using `str_replace()`
- `explode()` string using `,` to array of integers.
- `explode()` every element using `-` to check if it's a range or just a single integer.
- if it's a `range` , loop using `for()` or `range()` and add `$i` to `$newArray` , else add the element to `$newArray`.
- `implode()` using `,` and print the result.

**PHP code :**

```
<?php
       $str=str_replace(' ', '', '1, 4, 7, 20-25, 31, 46, 100');
       $arr = explode(',',$str);
        foreach($arr as $elem){
           $values=explode('-',$elem);
          if(count($values)!=1)  for($i=$values[0];$i<=$values[1];$i++)   $newArr[]=$i;
          else $newArr[]=$elem;
        }
       echo implode(',',$newArr);
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1,4,7,20,21,22,23,24,25,31,46,100
```